# Laravel get list of "completed" rows based on child table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

here's my problem that I just can't figure out:
I have a Clients table and a Boxes table.
Each box belongs to a Client.
I need to display all Clients where all Boxes belonging to each client is completed, which is basically WHERE box.status = "Completed".

I'm having trouble grasping how to do this all in one query:
-Get all Clients
-Get count of all boxes that belong to each client ($totalBoxes)
-Get count of completed boxes that belong to each client ($completedBoxes)
-Calculate if $completedBoxes = $totalBoxes
-Display only clients where $completedBoxes = $totalBoxes

I used this to get the number of $totalBoxes for Client.id = 2

```
Client::leftJoin('boxes', 'clients.id','=', 'boxes.clients_id')  
          ->where('clients_id','=',2)  
          ->select('clients.id','boxes.clients_id','boxes.status as status')  
          ->count();
```

I used this to get the number of $completedBoxes for Client.id = 2

```
Client::leftJoin('boxes', 'clients.id','=', 'boxes.clients_id')  
          ->where('clients_id','=',2)  
          ->where('boxes.status','=',"Completed")  
          ->select('clients.id','boxes.clients_id','boxes.status as status')  
          ->count();
```

```
if ($completedBoxes == $totalBoxes) {  
   //echo Client row..  
}
```

I just don't know how I can dynamically perform these subqueries within the main query/loop of Client row..

Example:

**Clients (id)**
1
2
3

**Boxes (id, client_id, status)**
1,1,Processing
2,1,Completed
**3,2,Completed**
**4,2,Completed**
5,3,Processing
6,3,Completed

**So my expected result is:**

**List of Completed Clients**
-Client 2

Help is much appreciated, thanks so much!

**EDIT**

Hey Chin - thanks so much, this helped me get to what I needed!
I ended up using the following code in my controller, which is returning the results that I want. However, what is the best way to display this in the blade?

```
$clients = Client::all();

foreach ($clients as $client){
  $active = $client->boxes()
        ->where('status', '!=' ,'Shipping')
        ->select('client_id')
        ->orderBy('client_id')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
  echo $active;
}
```

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
$completedClients = Client::boxes()
        ->where('status', '!=' ,'Shipping')
        ->select('client_id')
        ->orderBy('client_id')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

Then I would be able to run my loop in my blade, but Client::boxes is the incorrect syntax. In the link you referenced, the example is finding(1), but I need it to run for each Client.

Thanks again!

**EDIT 2**
Hey, sorry for the late reply, I noticed that the originally proposed solution was not returning the right results Here's my latest code:

```
$completed = Client::whereHas('boxes', function (Builder $query) {
                      $query->where('status', '=', 'Shipping');
                    })
                    ->select('id')
                    ->orderBy('id','asc')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->get();
```

So the problem is that it's returning a Client where any Box.status = Completed. I need to only return Clients with ALL Boxes = Completed. In my original post, the example client that should be returned is Client #2, because all their boxes = Completed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

In the Client model add something like this:

```
public function Boxes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Box');
}
```

And in the controller something like this:

```
$clients = Client::all();
return $clients->Boxes()->where('status', 'Completed')->get();
```

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work. That code only works if $clients is a specified client id.
Example that code works only if:
$clients = Client::find(1)

I want to loop through all the clients.

Comment: This is just a partial code to help you on your way. If you want to loop, then do a `foreach` on all clients first and then start the loop

Comment: Hi I just updated my post, I need it to only return Clients that have ALL Boxes = Completed. The solution above returns if ANY Box that belongs to a Client has Status=Completed. Thanks!

Comment: Then you need to loop through `$clients as $client` and get the boxes using `$client->Boxes()->where('status', 'Completed')->get()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add a relation between the `Client` and `Box` classes.

```
class Client extends Model
{
    public function boxes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Box::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the `whereDoesntHave` to query all the clients that does not have any boxes that are not completed.

```
$clients = Client::whereDoesntHave(['boxes' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', '!=', 'Completed');
});
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Comment: Hey thanks so much, this helped me get to what I needed!

Comment: @coderaging No problem. Please mark my answer as correct when you can. :)

Comment: Hey! I just updated my post, can you help me with that last bit and I'll mark it as an answer and close this topic. Thanks!!

Comment: @coderaging I don't understand what your updated question is. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yeah sure, I basically want to use this code in my blade  
`$clients = Client::all();

foreach ($clients as $client){
  $active = $client->boxes()
        ->where('status', '!=' ,'Shipping')
        ->select('client_id')
        ->orderBy('client_id')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
  echo $active;
}`
  
This code is in my controller, but I need to display it in my blade. 
My question is how can I display this loop within my blade. I know I can add it to an array but I think it's not the correct solution, also it takes awhile to load.

Comment: @coderaging Why not pass the `$clients` variable and use `@foreach` to loop inside your blade?

Comment: Hey I figured out how to loop it within the controller, however I realized the original problem still exists. See Edit #2